# What is \function in php?

Tags: php, function, syntax

sorry for the dumb question but I have this code here and I am really confused:

```
    $parsedResponse = \json_decode($this->response->getBody(), true);
```

What does the \ stand for before json_decode?

Thanks

Comment: It's a namespace separator. Namespaces where introduced with PHP/5.3.0.

Comment: See [the manual about namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php)